# ZIP from Ant build fails to extract from Cornerstone LMS CSOD

Tags: java, ant, zip, cornerstone

I have an Ant build which ends with a simple ZIP task:

```
<target name="packModule" description="Pack the SCO ZIP">
    <zip destfile="${deploy.dir}/sco_${module}_${lang}.zip" basedir="${deploy.dir}" />
</target>
```

This generates a ZIP file which gets deployed fine on many LMS, including SCORM Cloud. But on CSOD, it throws this error:

```
Error: Failed to unzip: Zip64 Extended information found but version is not valid
```

Right now, I have to manually unzip the package generated by Ant Build and rezip using 7-Zip to fix the issue. Please help me resolve this. Am on Windows7, using Ant version: apache-ant-1.9.6 and my JRE is jre1.8.0_45

Comment: According the [Zip64 extensions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html#zip64) section of the Ant documentation, you can turn it off with `zip64Mode="never"`, as long as all the files in your archive are smaller than 4 GB and you have fewer than 65536 entries total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VGR, `zip64Mode="never"` fixed the issue. I confirm it works fine on CSOD and doesn't require a manual unzip-zip routine. The final task looks like this:

```
<target name="packModule" description="Pack the SCO ZIP">
    <zip zip64Mode="never" destfile="${deploy.dir}/sco_${module}_${lang}.zip" basedir="${deploy.dir}" />
</target>
```